# <img src="images/thumbs/<?php echo e($homePostFour->photo->name); ?>" alt="<?php echo e($homePostFour->title); ?>" style="width:100%;">

Tags: php

Please help me with this error , ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /home/moecs6zz/moec-sdps/resources/views/front/index.blade.php)
the view line is:photo->name); ?>" alt="title); ?>" style="width:100%;">

Comment: Please print this `$homePostFour` and check if `$homePostFour->photo` and then `$homePostFour->photo->name` exists

Comment: Could you please tell me where to check it ?

Comment: on your view file just above the `<img` tag

Comment: use `print_r($homePostFour);` to see if it has values of `photo` and `title`

Comment: /div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="homepost">
                                <img src="images/thumbs/<?php echo e($homePostThree->photo->name); ?>" alt="<?php echo e($homePostThree->title); ?>" style="width:100%;">
                                <div class="bottom-right"><a href="<?php echo e(route('front.show', $homePostThree->id)); ?>"><?php echo e(trim(str_limit($homePostThree->title,50))); ?></a></div>

Comment: @Ash-b that is the view

Answer (score 1):

this is your code:

```
 photo->name
```

Please check your photo array. there are have a name property and here it Updates it:

```
 photo['name']
```

Comment: I should change it ?

Comment: I think so. if photo->name is not working then you can change it.